# Count() returns different number of entries than var_dump()

Tags: php, count

Hey guys I'm tired and can't figure this one out so any help would be appreciated.

I have an array called $Row that I get from database table.

When I run `var_dump($Row);` I get the following:

```
array
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string 'erik' (length=4)
  'username' => string 'erik' (length=4)
  2 => string 'd95eb19a15301089985ad6fd6ecbf2d7' (length=32)
  'password' => string 'd95eb19a15301089985ad6fd6ecbf2d7' (length=32)
  3 => string '' (length=0)
  'email' => string '' (length=0)
  4 => string '0' (length=1)
  'date_join' => string '0' (length=1)
  5 => string '0' (length=1)
  'date_mod' => string '0' (length=1)
  6 => string '1' (length=1)
  'active' => string '1' (length=1)
  7 => string '1' (length=1)
  'admin' => string '1' (length=1)
  8 => string '0' (length=1)
  'deleted' => string '0' (length=1)
```

When I run `echo count($Row);` I get value `18`.

Count and var_dump are right next to each other, there is no modification of $Row.

Question: Why does `Count()` return 18 entried when there are only `8` of them inside $Row shown by `var_dump()`? I guess I just don't understand `count()`... I checked http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php, but still don't get it...

Edit: I understand whats wrong know, thanks everyone. Another question. How can I remove the ones that are in a string, for instance I want this kind of a table:

```
array
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string 'erik' (length=4)
  2 => string 'd95eb19a15301089985ad6fd6ecbf2d7' (length=32)
  3 => string '' (length=0)
  4 => string '0' (length=1)
  5 => string '0' (length=1)
  6 => string '1' (length=1)
  7 => string '1' (length=1)
  8 => string '0' (length=1)
```

*** I'm using mysql_fetch_array() to retrieve the data and put it into a table.

Comment: I see 18 entries in var_dump too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having mixed array integer and associative and having 18 elements. This is I think returned from `mysql_fetch_array` which by default return associative and numeric indexed array.

Answer (score 1):

Because your strings are also values in `$Row` they just seem to be indented because of the string char.
That means

```
'id' => string '1' (length=1)
'username' => string 'erik' (length=4)
'password' => string 'd95eb19a15301089985ad6fd6ecbf2d7' (length=32)
// ...
```

are also in your array

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are indeed 18 elements in your array:

- indices `0` through `8` (9 elements in total)
- `id`, `username`, ... another 9 elements

9 + 9 = 18

If you only want the numeric indices, and supposing you're using MySQL:

```
$Row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1):

becuase you're getting back a mix of associative and numeric result set from you db ( you can precise which one you really want with FETCH_ASSOC or alike as a parameter to you dbvendor_query() function ).

There is very well 18 elements in your array.

Comment: I'm just guessing that you're using mysql. try replacing you mysql_fetch_row() with mysql_fetch_assoc() then check out the results ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think that applying count to this:

```
0 => string '1' (length=1)
'id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

returns 2 instead of 1!

0 and id are two different items of the array!
This taken for the others 8 elements make the count return 18

Comment: Can you show the structure of the table, the sql query you execute and the php code used to retreive the values after the query is executed? My feeling is that you perform operations on the array making it having not a proper structure...